# Can I run kafka producer and consumer on the same server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka and am trying to learn on how to implement kafka producer and consumer on the same machine and am not able to understand on how to proceed with it. I want the producer and consumer to run simultaneously. Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can also run the broker (the third part you will need) there as well. Or they can all run on different machines. All they need to be able to do is connect to the broker over the network.

Comment: you can use docker if you want to do the same in different containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download Kafka tar file and extract it.
Then go to bin directory and execute following command.
Note: producer and consumer command must run in different tab so that in one tab you can produce json and in other you can consume on console.

To create topic:

```
kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic test_topic
```

To run Producer on console

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test_topic
```

To run consumer on console

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test_topic --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.As both producer will produce on topic.the same topic will be read by consumer. you can try out with this:
https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example